# Can anyone describe to me what is happening in this AI file? Jagged edges, non vector?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, print-design, shapes, path

I'm not exactly sure of how to even describe this, but have attached screenshots from the Illustrator file a friend sent me, so that I could quickly change the colors of a logo for her. This file came from a designer she hired to create a brand identity, but when I open the file, I am completely perplexed as to how they created the images. She also sent over pngs, which are appearing with jagged, white edges. Any idea of how to explain in the proper design language to her and the designer why this file is unusable?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Impossible to state -- but it somewhat looks like someone used some non-Illustrator app to trace shapes, then exported to Illustrator (or SVG or EPS). The O in particular just looks like a *very* bad auto-trace. There's no logical reason an actual Bezier construction - in Illustrator, Inkscape, etc would look like *that*. It's more closely related to what one sees when if someone were to use Flash (or some other app), then exported to AI format. -- I am **guessing** here. There is also the distinct possibly the person your friend hired had no clue what they were doing.

Comment: There's also the possibility that the individual traced shapes. Then, in AI, hid the original PNG images which were traced... if you hide things in AI, they can pop back up when the file is exported or saved to various formats (EPS is notable for this.)

Comment: It might also be a graphics bug try doing **View -> View using CPU**. I noticed in latest builds that some of the conditions no longer work right with GPU rendering. Also hide any bitmap

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have something like this:

[image]

Turn antialiasing ON in the Preferences and turn Pixel Preview OFF from the View menu. After doing them the computer screen contains this:

[image]

Your images seem to have a mass of anchor points. It's like a bitmap image has been traced. Nobody has time to draw that many manually. The "artist" either thinks you are blind or dumb or he cannot at all draw clean vector shapes with as few anchors as possible.

Comment: +1 Good suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't think either pixel preview nor anti-aliasing will result in the poor artwork in the question.

Answer (score 0):

PNG files are not vector files as they are placed raster images in AI. This looks like an imported image from a raster based app like photoshop. You can use Image Trace to make them vector, but it may affect the shapes.